# Finding the greatest number in an array less than or equal to a target

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is what I am doing.
I have an array (or vector), V and then I am sorting it in ascending order.
The highest number less than or equal to target `a` will be at position `i`.(initially, `i = 0`)

```
while (V[i] <= a && i < V.size()) { i++; }
 i--;
```

I am using this part of a code in a question on Codechef, and getting AC, however earlier I was using this and was getting it wrong.

```
while (V[i+1] <= a && i < V.size()-1) i++;
```

Aren't the two doing essentially the same thing? Why would I be getting WA with second rather than first? Could you point out a testcase for which they would be different?

For example in a testcase:

> V = 5,7,10,12
>
> a = 11

Both end with `i = 2`.

Another similar issue I am getting is this:

I have another list of SORTED values say V2, which I am traversing. For each value x, I am trying to find the highest number in V that is less than or equal to x. This is what I was doing earlier:

```
while (V[i] <= x && i < V.size()) {
        i++;
    }
i--;
```

Each iteration through V2, I was not setting the value of i as 0, but instead was continuing from where I was earlier. (Because V2 was sorted)

So if I have:

> V = 5 7 10 12
>
> V2 = 7 8 10 11 13

My code would return index 1, 1, 2, 2, 3. Even then, I was getting WA with this. :/

But when before each iteration through V2 I was doing i = 0, I was getting AC. Now this is slow, which is not what I wanted to do initially, but I have no idea why it isn't working when I don't reset i to 0.

Help, guys? :3

EDIT:
You can replace the values here.

```
vector <int> V1 = {1,2,3};
int target = 5;
int index = 0;
while (V1[index] <= target && index < V1.size()) { index++; }
index--;
cout << index << endl;
index = 0;
while (V1[index+1] <= target && index < V1.size()-1) index++;
cout << index << endl;
```

This^ always seems to return same answer for each testcase provided.

Comment: Your second code will not check `i=0`, so they are not equal

Comment: hmm.. Could you look for a testcase?

Comment: `V = 5,7,10,12` `a=6` maybe?

Comment: and why you not use `<algorithm>`?

Comment: You need to define what you want when there is no such number in the array.

Comment: What in <algorithm> ? And @appleapple both return 0 for the testcase you provided.

Comment: Not sure about the specs of the problem but your code will blow up for a test case V=1,2,3 & A=5 . You need to swap your checks in the while so 'i < V.size()' is first.

Comment: How does swapping checks make a difference? :/ I tried that test case and both code returned 2.

Comment: @SinByCos if you do not provide us [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can only guess :/

Comment: @appleapple does my Edit help?

Comment: @SinByCos will it be (`V = 5,7,10,12` / `a=4`)?

Comment: @SinByCos `<algorithm>` is a `c++` header contains many useful algorithms

Comment: @appleapple I asked what IN <algorithm> :p I already know what it is but I don't remember any algorithm that would help me with this. But yeah in that test case I am getting -1 with the first code. But still that code is the one which gives AC.. Gotta look into this hm.

Comment: @SinByCos --   If the array is sorted, please investigate using `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`.  Iterating through the entire sorted array is the naive approach.  The array is sorted, thus a binary search is all you need to find the value.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why are you sorting? Depending on the sort algorithm, your time complexity will be at least O(n log n)... Where as if you iterate over the unsorted vector the complexity is only O(n).

Comment: @Leon Read the "other issue I am getting" :p I was sorting so that it would eliminate iterating over the whole list again and again. And anyway, I think normally sorting would still be faster because it would be slower over a large array. Sorting would exit the loop as soon as it finds an element greater than the target.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Doesn't lower_bound and upper_bound miss an element if it is not equal to the target? For eg V = {1,2,3,5} and a = 4, lower_bound would give V.end() as far as I remember? Not sure, so please clarify.

Comment: @SinByCos OK, so you sorted the array.  Then you went right back and started to iterate through the sorted array to find the value.  You've thrown away the reason why you sorted the array to begin with.  Use the binary searching algorithms I mentioned.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think you are misunderstanding.. I am not looking for the value, I am looking for a value less than or equal to the target. lower_bound and upper_bound don't help with that.

Comment: @SinByCos [See this](http://ideone.com/0QnFRx).  Even if you didn't know about lower_bound and upper_bound, think about what you're doing.  You sorted the array, and then you're trying to find a value that's less than or equal to a certain value.  You don't naively iterate one by one to find that value -- you use a binary search.

Comment: @SinByCos are you get V2 as input? is V2 always sorted?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but won't it be slower if I have to upper_bound again and again through V2? If I remember what 'i' was in the previous iteration and continue from there it should be faster, right?

Comment: @SinByCos If you had a million sorted numbers, and the value that you're looking for happened to be at the very end of the sorted list, iterating one-by-one would take a million comparisons using your method.  A binary search would take only a maximum of 20 comparisons to find the goal value.  Not a fan of online coding sites, but that is probably the reason you're getting timed out in your attempt at this.

Comment: Okay, thanks! You could submit as answer and I would upvote accept :p

Comment: @SinByCos I added the solution and explanation why it is faster than doing a linear search on a sorted array.

Answer (score 1):

Since the array to search is already sorted, you can use the various binary search algorithm functions to find the correct value.  Using a binary search is `O(log n)` complexity to find the value, as opposed to the search that you're using, which is `O(n)`.

To put it another way, if there were a million numbers in your sorted array, searching one-by-one to find the right value would take a maximum of a million comparisons.  Using a binary search would take a maximum of 20 comparison, where the comparison is only done on the middle element of a shrinking sequence (the sequence is cut in half each time the number is not found).

In `<algorithm>` there is [std::upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) that can be used to do the binary search.  The trick is to return the value that comes before the iterator that `std::upper_bound` returns, and making sure that you don't go out of bounds at the lower end of the values to search.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int getIndex(const std::vector<int>& V, int val)
{
    auto iter = std::upper_bound(V.begin(), V.end(), val);
    if ( iter != V.begin())
       // return the index of the item before the found item
       return std::distance(V.begin(), std::prev(iter));

    // return the first item
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> V = {5,7,10,12};
   std::vector<int> V2 = {7, 8, 10, 11, 13};
   std::for_each(V2.begin(), V2.end(), [&](int val)
   {std::cout << getIndex(V, val) << " ";});
}
```

[See Live Example](http://ideone.com/0QnFRx)

Note that the example doesn't check if the value to find is less than any values in your vector.  You need to add this check and return a value denoting the number is out of range.